# If I change the taxonomy of a post will it get a new time stamp?

Tags: categories, timestamp

I have a category called feature that displays the latest post, but further down the line if the user wants to make an older post a featured post, it doesn't currently work. Using the time stamp would be a good hook to implement this, I'm assuming if the user was to check the feature category on an older post and update, would it get a new time stamp? Therefore I could display the most recent time stamped post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making a couple of assumptions:

1. I assume that by "I have a category called feature that displays the
   latest post" you mean that you are displaying the latest posts in
   your "featured" category
2. I assume that your "featured" categories have their own template
   which has a query that displays them.

Assuming those assumptions to be correct, you need to alter the query that pulls your featured categories so that it sorts by `post_modified` instead of `post_date`. If you will post your query I will show you how to do that.

Comment: aha! Your assumptions were correct! Thank you kindly.